# Passing in element properties to ng-class expressions

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if it's possible to use `ng-class` and supply an expression that's based on the inner content of the element it's being used on.

So for example, say I have:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
        <td ng-class="vm.getNumberClass(...)">
            {{vm.getSomeMagicNumber(result)}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Could I pass in the value of the `td` cell content as an argument to the `getNumberClass` function I am using as an expression on the `ng-class` directive?

**EDIT**

When I say pass in the value of the td cell content, I mean pass in the evaluated result of `{{vm.getSomeMagicNumber(result)}}` as an argument

I could do something like.

```
<td ng-class="vm.getNumberClass(vm.getSomeMagicNumber(result))">
    {{vm.getSomeMagicNumber(result)}}
</td>
```

Whilst this does work for my scenario, it feels like a performance hit as its calling the function twice

Comment: Of course you can, if it's on the same scope. Your loop is above your `ng-class` and above your `<td>`, so you can call `result` from both. You can even use `result` variable at the same level as the loop `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Yeah, thats not quite what I meant, see my edit, I see you just posted an answer and quickly deleted again, but see you suggested the same thing as I have ended up with so far

Comment: I updated my answer from your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are willing to do inside these functions.

Here is what I'd do to avoid calling the function twice, you'll have to store the result somewhere (If it's not on the CPU, it has to be on the RAM):

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.getNumberClass = function(number) {
    var className = '';

    switch (parseInt(number)) {
      case 3:
        className = 'red';
        break;
      case 6:
        className = 'coral';
        break;
      case 9:
        className = 'pink';
        break;
    }
    
    return className;
  };

  vm.getSomeMagicNumber = function(result) {
    // Any process here and store the result for each row
    result.magicNumber = result.id * 3;
    
    return result.magicNumber;
  };

  vm.results = [{
    id: '1'
  }, {
    id: '2'
  }, {
    id: '3'
  }];
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.coral {
  background-color: coral;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results">
      <td ng-class="vm.getNumberClass(result.magicNumber)">
        {{vm.getSomeMagicNumber(result)}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```